# repeating steps in GRASS r.mapcalc

Tags: grass-gis, iteration, shell

I simply cannot find out the following: I want to repeat a calculation in GRASS GIS several times. Is there a command for r.mapcalc to repeat a calculation x times (similar to this possibility in r.mfilter, for example)....besides listing that step x times in s shell scripts (I use shell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call r.mapcalc in for loop. In shell it could look like this:

```
X=5
# initialize first map
r.mapcalc "old = 10"

# loop
for I in `seq $X` 
do
  r.mapcalc "new = old + 10" --overwrite
  g.rename rast=new,old --overwrite
done
```

In shell command `seq 5` creates a sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5.

Note that you shouldn't use r.mapcalc like this (read from and write in the same map):

```
r.mapcalc "old = old + 10" --overwrite
```

Comment: The loop in one line: `for I in \`seq $X\`; do r.mapcalc "new = old + 10" --overwrite && g.rename rast=new,old --overwrite; done` ;-)